# Is it possible in Krusader to add custom icons and custom commands to execute?

Tags: kde, file-manager

In Krusader, is it possible to add custom icons to execute custom commands?
I would like to configure something like my working environment - with icons as shortcuts to execute scripts etc. If it is not possible with Krusader is there another file manager that allows me to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you trying to import your Total Commander configuration into Krusader? Or are you trying to duplicate a similar functionality, and if so, which?

Comment: Duplicate a feature - put on toolbar links for execute programs. Should I add more details?

Comment: Yes, please add a short description of the feature you want to duplicate, so that people who know Krusader but not Total Commander can help you.

Comment: Please.e.g. add on toolbar icon of Eclipse and if I click on this icon Eclipse should be started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean what I think you mean then yes, that is possible

In **Useractions > Manage User Action** you hit **Create new useraction**.
Here you can configure your shortcut to Eclipse. You'll need at least **Identifier, Title** (eg. Eclipse) and **Command** (eg. /opt/eclipse/eclipse). If you need to, you can also change the **Advanced Properties** of the shortcut to change its behaviour depending what you are doing in your file panes (for instance, only working when you have an Eclipse project file selected).

Next, in **Settings > Configure Toolbars** with the Main Toolbar selected simply add your new shortcut to where you need it to be on your toolbar.

You can configure as many User Actions as you like.

e2a - Don't forget to add an icon to your User Action so you can see it in your toolbar. The one that comes with Eclipse (eg. /opt/eclipse/icon.xpm) should do you fine.